# Sql export for select result

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to export data from database but in phpmyadmin i have no option to dump it to sql format.

```
SELECT email 
FROM users, 
     profiles 
WHERE users.id = profiles.user_id 
  AND profiles.country_id = 1
```

I'm not good in sql - why i cant dump this to sql format form phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is export option below the results.
[image]

EDIT:

You need to select single table e.g.

```
SELECT email
FROM   users
WHERE  userid IN (SELECT userid
                  FROM   users,
                         profiles
                  WHERE  users.id = profiles.user_id
                         AND profiles.country_id = 1)
```

Comment: yes know how to do it and i do it but with this select i dont have format to SQL. When you click "export" you can choose in which format you want to save dump - and there is no SQL for this select

Comment: I see ... it can't generate SQL, cuz of joined tables

Comment: so how can i dump to sql format that kind of data? I need emails from users where profiles.country_id = 2